# upgrading AspectJ + Spring + Gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, java-8, aspectj

I am trying to upgrade the AspectJ jar from 1.8.1 to 1.8.5 but my build keeps failing with the following error:

```
[ant:iajc] [error] javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: createResource. Resource already created
```

The build was fine before the update. I tried to do another upgrade from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2 and that failed as well. 
Here is a snippet of my build.gradle

```
ext.aspectjCompiler = {
    ant.taskdef(
            resource: 'org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties',
            classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath
            )
    ant.iajc(
            source: sourceCompatibility,
            target: targetCompatibility,
            destDir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath,
            maxmem: '512m',
            fork: 'true',
            aspectPath: configurations.aspects.asPath,
            sourceRootCopyFilter:'**/*.java',
            classpath: "${configurations.compile.asPath};${configurations.aspectCompile.asPath}",
            Xlint: 'ignore'
            ){
                sourceroots {
                    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { srcDir ->
                        pathelement(location: srcDir.absolutePath)
                    }
                }
            }
}

compileJava {
    doLast aspectjCompiler
}
```

Comment: Always provide full stacktraces, not just the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Since [AspectJ 1.8.2](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-182.html) the AspectJ compiler *ajc* supports annotation processing. This was also described in a [blog post](http://andrewclement.blogspot.de/2014/08/annotation-processing-in-ajdt.html) by AspectJ maintainer Andy Clement. Probably this is somehow getting in the way of other APT stuff in your project.

Unfortunately, the command line interface for *ajc* does not mention or explain the new parameters (only showing error messages when using them wrongly), but basically there are three: `-proc`, `-processor` and `-processorpath`. Searching in the source code, you even find some inline documentation:

From [AjcTask.java](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/784906d2ee0cb1b432a9aff6973c12cfd865db6e/taskdefs/src/org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/AjcTask.java#L464):

```java
  /**
   * Controls whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
   * -proc:none means that compilation takes place without annotation processing.
   * -proc:only means that only annotation processing is done, without any subsequent compilation.
   */
  public void setProc(String proc) {
    if (proc.equals("none")) {
      cmd.addFlag("-proc:none", true);
    } else if (proc.equals("only")) {
      cmd.addFlag("-proc:only", true);
    }
  }

  /**
   * -processor class1[,class2,class3...]
   *  Names of the annotation processors to run. This bypasses the default discovery process.
   */
  public void setProcessor(String processors) {
    cmd.addFlagged("-processor", processors);
  }

  /**
   * -processorpath path
   * Specify where to find annotation processors; if this option is not used, the class path will be searched for processors.
   */
  public void setProcessorpath(String processorpath) {
    cmd.addFlagged("-processorpath", processorpath);
  }
```

Some test code from [AjcTaskTest.java](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/784906d2ee0cb1b432a9aff6973c12cfd865db6e/taskdefs/testsrc/org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/AjcTaskTest.java#L788):

```java
  public void testAptProc() {
    AjcTask task = getTask(NOFILE);
    task.setProc("none");
    checkContains(task.makeCommand(), "-proc:none", true);
    task.setProc("only");
    checkContains(task.makeCommand(), "-proc:only", true);
  }

  public void testAptProcessor() {
    AjcTask task = getTask(NOFILE);
    task.setProcessor("some.SomeClass");
    checkContains(task.makeCommand(), "-processor", true);
    checkContains(task.makeCommand(), "some.SomeClass", true);
  }

  public void testAptProcessorpath() {
    AjcTask task = getTask(NOFILE);
    task.setProcessorpath("some/path");
    checkContains(task.makeCommand(), "-processorpath", true);
    checkContains(task.makeCommand(), "some/path", true);
  }

  public void testAptGeneratedDirectory() {
    AjcTask task = getTask(NOFILE);
    task.setS("some/path");
    checkContains(task.makeCommand(), "-s", true);
    checkContains(task.makeCommand(), "some/path", true);
  }
```

So maybe you want to use `-proc:none` in your Ant job when calling *ajc* so as go step out of the way of what you do with APT in another build step. The other option would be to configure *ajc* such that it does the annotation processing for you instead of the other APT build step.