# How to debug build errors when using AspectJ compiler? Specifically one pointing out a resource has already been created?

Tags: xml, build, ant, aspectj, lombok

I am working with a codebase that uses aspectJ to compile our sourcecode and have been getting a ServiceAnnotation error about a resource already existing.  I think it has something to do with how the build.xml is configured for our project.

Not sure where to begin when trying to resolve this error.

```
[iajc] [error   0]: error Uncaught exception in 
ServiceAnnotationProcessor:
 [iajc] javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Resource 
 already created : CLASS_OUTPUT//META- 
INF/annotated/com.service.annotation.Service
```

Here is how the build.xml file is configured with respects to AspectJ

```
<taskdef resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${bp:[AspectJTools]lib.classpath}" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="compile" depends="ht-pre-compile,iajc-compile,ht-post-compile" />
```

Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I could help you with AspectJ Maven, not with Ant. I never used Ant, not even in the olden days. Anyway, the reason I am writing is in order to explain to you that a little snippet out of context will not do. Please reduce your project into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share that with us here or on GitHub. Otherwise anyone trying to help you could just guess, but I think what you want instead is substantial help based on analysis after reproducing your problem.

Comment: Sounds like the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598597/upgrading-aspectj-spring-gradle